# Python Text Files to list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm opening a file that might be something like this...

> It was the best of times,
>
> it was the worst of times.

Let's say this file name is myFile1.txt

I want the file to split up into this

```
[['It','was','the','best','of','times',','],
 ['it','was', 'the','worst','of','times','.']]
```

It should be a list of strings...

This is my idea...

```
def Split():
  inFile=open('myFile1.txt','r')

  for line in inFile:
    separate=list(line.split())
    return(separate)

print(Split())
```

would something like this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your desired list by declaring `separate = []` outside of the loop, and then appending the result of `line.split()` to the list.  You don't need to use the `list` function, as `line.split()` already returns a list.

You could try this:

```
def Split():
  separate = []
  with open('myFile1.txt','r') as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
      separate.append(line.split())
  return(separate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Split():
    results=[]
    inFile=open('myFile1.txt','r')
    for line in inFile.readlines():
        results.append(line.split())
    return results

print(Split())
```

Then everything should work fine. :)

Comment: This just makes it store all of the file in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning after only one pass through the for loop.

What you want is a generator, using yield instead of return:

```
yield separate
```

Now your function creates a generator object that can be iterated over.

```
for line in split():
    print line
```

(Also, it's probably better not to name your function the same as a built-in method. They probably won't clash, but better safe than sorry.)

Comment: Also also, line.split() already returns a list. You don't need to construct another list from it.